# How to get rid of jquery accordion "Default:first child"?

Tags: jquery, accordion

By default first child is shown always in jquery accordion .... How to get rid of  [active](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) `default value` which is `active` on `document.ready` function such that none of the child shows up......

I am using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selector").accordion({ active: \\ how to set active none here });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried `active: false` and it worked...

Answer (score 2):

That will work "active : false".  You can also set which one you want to turn on by default by doing "active : 3".  Note the numbering starts at zero.